# Sql Query Results to CSV format doesn't include the correct date values

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, csv

Following is my query

Following is my table structure

Table Name: Person

```
      ID:  (PK,int, not null)
      Name: (Nvarchar(20),null)
      BirthDate : (Datetime,null)
```

Following is my query

```
      select Name,BirthDate From Person
```

Output is as follows

```
      Name   BirthDate
      Sam    1986-01-01
      Bob    2001-04-07
      John   2000-02-02
```

Output in CSV

```
      Name   BirthDate
      Sam    00:00.0
      Bob    00:00.0
      John   00:00.0
```

In order to export this content to csv all i do is select the values and right click on the output window with "copy with headers" option.
it creates the CSV fine but when i open the file i get BirthDate as 00:00.0 for all three values.
I don't understand what's causing this. Please help.

Comment: Sounds like you are opening the file in excel and excel is just formatting the date incorrectly. What happens if you open the file in notepad (or similar)?

Comment: Thank you GarethD. I didnt notice that.  Is there a way to open this in excel in correct format?

Comment: Not as far as I am aware. The original value should still be there, it is just formatted as `mm:ss.0` as this is what excel deems to be the best format (I have no idea why - the same thing happens when pasting a datetime into excel), just change the format to whatever you require after opening the file.

Comment: No problem. I think if you use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), BirthDate, 120)` to export the date, excel will then convert it to a date format rather than `mm:ss.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the output to:

```
Name;BirthDate
Sam;"1986-01-01"
Bob;"2001-04-07"
John;"2000-02-02"
```

This way in Excel the dates will show normally (I added ";" as sep but of course this can be tab or anything else).